# CosmosDB Emulator Linux Image - Mount Volume

Tags: linux, docker, azure-cosmosdb

What is the correct path for mapping a directory into the cosmosDB emulator linux docker image so that data (databases) are persisted on the host file system?

```
 cosmosdb:
        container_name: cosmosdb
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
        mem_reservation: 3G
        cpu_count: 2
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
            - "8900:8900"
            - "8901:8901"
            - "8979:8979"
            - "10250:10250"
            - "10251:10251"
            - "10252:10252"
            - "10253:10253"
            - "10254:10254"
            - "10255:10255"
            - "10256:10256"
            - "10350:10350"
        environment:
            AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT: 3
            AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE: true
            AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE: 127.0.0.1
        volumes:
           - ???
```

For Windows it seems to be

```
C:/CosmosDB.Emulator/bind-mount
```

I already have taken a look into the running image but i have no clue in which directoy database/data files are stored...

As so often the docu is rather short
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=sql-api%2Cssl-netstd21

and it just says

```
If the Cosmos DB emulator data folder is "volume mounted", ensure that the volume has enough space and is read/write.
```

But what is the data folder? ;)

Comment: try /usr/local/bin/cosmos

Comment: nope, there are no database files inside it

Comment: weird... if you spin up your container with interactive and then 'ps' the processes and then ''pwdx <PID>" then thats the location of the running process...

Answer (score 10):

/tmp/cosmos/appdata

found it by running docker in interactive and the the "find / cosmos" command...
i didnt get any found results but it output a list of all the directories it scanned... and i found that path. just tested and it works.

this is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  default:
    external: false
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"

services:
  cosmosdb:
    container_name: "azurecosmosdbemulatorcontainer"
    hostname: "azurecosmosdbemulatorhostname"
    image:  mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
    platform: linux
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    mem_limit: 3GB
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
      - '8900:8900'
      - '8901:8901'
      - '8902:8902'
      - '10250:10250'
      - '10251:10251'
      - '10252:10252'
      - '10253:10253'
      - '10254:10254'
      - '10255:10255'
      - '10256:10256'
      - '10350:10350'
    environment:
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT: 2
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE: true
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE: ${External_IP}
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.246
    volumes:
      - cosmosdrive:/tmp/cosmos/appdata

volumes:
  cosmosdrive:
  recipientdrive:
```

[image]

Comment: thx for the reply. got me a step further - i created a volume mount to store the whole CosmosDbEmulator in a local directory, therefore preserving also the loalemulator.db, sadly with this approach i can not start the docker image anymore 

rm: cannot remove '/tmp/cosmos/appdata/.system/profiles/Client/AppData/Local/CosmosDBEmulator

Comment: The mount path that works perfectly for me is /tmp/cosmos/appdata… why do you not want to use that path?

Comment: If i use volumes: - ./data/cosmos:/tmp/cosmos/appdata the image does not start anymore

Comment: What is your docker start command?

Comment: I’m mounting in a docker  compose file, will update my answer to show it, but also try to add :rw to the end of your path

Comment: Docker-compose part is totally fine - thx for the help!